# addClass to a parent element with a specific class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Question:** 
 1. How do I reference a parent element by class name?  And once I have referenced it how do I add a new class name while not removing the current class name?

2. How would I reference a sibling element by class name?

**Below is a structure of my current HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-pad">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeCount" name="employeeCount" placeholder="{{nls 'example_total_num'}}" value="{{employeeCount}}"></input>
                <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
                <div class="help-block">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-pad">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salesForceCount" name="salesForceCount" placeholder="{{nls 'example_sales_num'}}" value="{{salesForceCount}}"></input>
                <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
                <div class="help-block">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Below is the method that is tied to a blur event of the `#salesForceCount` input above:**

```
 procSalesForceCount: function (e) {
    let $e = $(e.currentTarget);
    let val = parseInt($e.val());
    val = isNaN(val) ? null: val;
if (val > this.model.get('employeeCount')) {

  var error_message = `${val} is larger than employee count ${this.model.get("employeeCount")}`;

//add new class has-error to parent div with form-group class 
   $e.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
  $e.siblings('.help-block').html(error_message);
  return;
}
// END

this.model.set({ salesForceCount: val });
  }
```

Comment: Your "question" is not a question. It is a pair of requirements. You've not said what it is about the code you have that is not working.

Comment: I did not make that clear.. The part that is not working is the two requirements. I am having issues adding the has-error class to the parent element with form-group class. And I am having issues adding my error_message to the sibling element with the help-block class. This can be found directly below my comment //add new class has-error to parent div with form-group class  in my method.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I tried to rephrase my post as a two part question. Please see my edit above.

Comment: The methods .parent, parents, .siblings all take on optional selector parameter.

Comment: Thanks CBroe I see one of my issues from the beginning I was missing the "s" on the end of siblings. I will try that again with it added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How do I reference a parent element by class name? And once I have referenced it how do I add a new class name while not removing the current class name?

```
$(child).closest(".class-name").addClass("new-class");
```

> 2. How would I reference a sibling element by class name?

```
$(selector).siblings(".class-name");
```

Or

```
$("selector + .class-name");
```

Comment: I have updated my questions to include the correct syntax as outlined in your answer above. These updates have fixed my issues. thanks! +1